# ROUND function is not working in mssql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
select ROUND(no_of_order, 2) from #temp
```

Here the no_of_order are `1.2345` and `45.43215` as values in my temp table.

BUT `ROUND` function doesnot round the value. I need an output as 1.24 and 45.43 correspondingly. Instead now i am getting the same set of no_of_order  `1.2345` and `45.43215`

Comment: Unable to reproduce the issue. `select ROUND(no_of_order, 2) from (select 1.2345 union all select 45.43215) a(no_of_order)` produces two rows with values 1.23 and 45.43 (no rounding method should produce the value 1.24 as in your question though)

Comment: 1.2345 will be made 1.23 nt 1.24 :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this :   [sql fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b9763/2)

```
 declare @v nvarchar(50) = '21.89777777777777777777777777'

        select convert(decimal(18,2),round(@v,2))
```